# Spring Boot Admin - custom tabs

Tags: spring-boot-admin

Spring Boot Admin is a great tool to start with.
However, we have few use custom Actuator endpoints which we would like to be added to the SBA preferably in a new tab section.

Somewhere I found "applications-activiti" being mentioned sometimes but that also seems to be decommissioned. Is there a good reference with example to do the same.

Comment: the activiti sample is in the 1.5.x branch https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/tree/1.5.x/spring-boot-admin-server-ui-activiti

for 2.0 there is currently no solution.

Comment: An Example of Adding new custom tab : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53462345/1131967